# "Multisystem" lost avareness of installed OS

Tags: grub2, iso, grubrescue

I was using Multisystem - http://liveusb.info/dotclear/
With it i had made USB multiboot with all these in one USB:
Ubuntu 10.04.04 persistent
Ubuntu 10.04.04 live
Ubuntu 12.04 live
Ubuntu 12.10 live
Windows XP
Windows 7

Last thing i did using Multiboot system was installing Boot repair
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

It must have nothing to do that i`ve installed boot-repair. Btw i didnt run boot-repair so nothing should be changed.
BUT since that on next comp putting Multisystem USB didnt find grub anymore so didnt worked Multiboot anymore.
Since then in Multisystem it shows empty screen- none of installed OS.
I did reinstll grub but that gave grub without all installed OS.

This kind of problem is not 1st time i need to reinstall all USB. Is there a way to make Multisystem see all already installed systems?
Also tried Multisystems Super Grub2 disk and it failed to start..
See pics. Shows no OS but they are in USB.
[image: Nautilus USB]
[image: Multisystem menu]

Answer (score 0):

If it is using grub2 as the boot loader you have grub.cfg.

And you can just add your own boot stanzas. One of the advantages of the script like dotclear's is that it gets the correct boot parameters for each install. When manually doing it that can be a bit difficult if you do not know otherwise. Good examples help.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples

Arch example

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Booting_an_ISO_directly_from_GRUB